# Message Passing in Python for stacks

Tags: python

By using message passing to fuifill the code such that

```
s = make_stack()
print(s("is_empty")) # True
s("push")(1) 
s("push")(2) 
print(s("peek"))     # [2]
print(str(s("pop"))) # [2]
```

My code is supposed to fill in the blanks of

```
def make_stack():
    items = []
    def oplookup(msg):
        if msg == "is_empty":
            # blank #
        elif msg == "clear":
            # blank #
        elif msg == "peek":
            # blank #
        elif msg == "push":
            # blank #
        elif msg == "pop":
            # blank #
        else:
            raise Exception("stack doesn't" + msg)
    return oplookup
```

I don't understand the tracing of the code. My own trial code is

```
def make_stack():
    items = []
    def oplookup(msg):
        if msg == "is_empty":=
            return True
        elif msg == "clear":
            return []
        elif msg == "peek":
            return make_stack.items[-1]
        elif msg == "push":
            return items.append(msg)
        elif msg == "pop":
            return items.pop()
        else:
            raise Exception("stack doesn't" + msg)
    return oplookup
```

Another question is for having s("push") (1), what argument does (1) take? Is it under msg or item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first issue you have is that you need to return something callable from `oplookup`, probably a function. The functions all need to manipulate (or test) the `items` list (which they can access because they are closures).

Here's what that code might look like:

```
def make_stack():
    items = []
    def oplookup(msg):
        if msg == "is_empty":
            def empty():
                return not items
            return empty
        elif msg == "clear":
            def clear():
                items[:] = [] # slice assignment, to clear in-place
            return clear
        #...
```

Note that in `clear` I avoid doing an assignment directly to `items` because it's in the enclosing scope. In Python 2, it's impossible to reassign `items`, since it is neither local or global variable. In Python 3, reassignment is possible using the `nonlocal` keyword. Since I don't know what version of Python you're using, I used a slice assignment which works in both versions.

This style of code is not very Pythonic. A much more natural way to do this would be to make a class with methods (but you'd end up with a slightly different API):

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def is_empty(self):
        return not self.items

    def clear(self):
        self.items = [] # this time we can replace the list

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    #...
```